# selenium - How can read the text from a web page & pass the same text in some other field as parameter

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Kindly provide appropriate solution for this Query ?

In Web sit,One customer page is there,Where it display the customer name, i wants to read this customer name and pass the same value in some other page in customer name Text Field.How can i do this ?

Comment: Please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) an answer if you think it solves your problem. It will community at large to recognize the correct solution. This can be done by clicking the green check mark next to the answer. See this [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png) for reference. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You can store the name of customer in the first page

```
String name= driver.findElement(By .id("searchString")).getAttribute("value");
```

and then call the string later whenever needed. If you want to pass the same value to some other field then you can use the code

```
driver.findElement(By .id("id of element")).sendKeys(name);
```

by calling the string here the name will be passed.

Comment: in the screen, the value is randomly generate ,we cant pass the name directly.

Comment: provide the details how the application works then you will get the appropriate answer. I have given the answer based on details provided. plz provide more details.. U can edit the question and provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

using httpGet you can read the values of the old customer and capture those values and pass them to the new form